# Understanding the Exception record in Debug Logs

Tags: exception, debugging

I am unable to access a certain VF page from the Customer Portal, I get the following standard error:

> Error: Error occurred while loading a Visualforce page.

So I added a trace flag for the running user and when I try to access that same page again, I see two new records in the debug log:

[image]

When I open the Exception record, I see no useful information that can help me resolve this error:

```
25.0 APEX_CODE,DEBUG;APEX_PROFILING,INFO;CALLOUT,INFO;DB,INFO;SYSTEM,DEBUG;VALIDATION,INFO;VISUALFORCE,INFO;WAVE,INFO;WORKFLOW,INFO
07:44:47.0 (67633)|USER_INFO|[EXTERNAL]|005w0000004MPM3|ddd.ddd@example.com.full|Central Standard Time|GMT-05:00
07:44:47.0 (104156)|EXECUTION_STARTED
07:44:47.0 (108423)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|06620000000AZxZ|VF: /apex/Exception
07:44:47.59 (59073955)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE
07:44:47.59 (59073955)|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|(default)|
  Number of SOQL queries: 0 out of 100
  Number of query rows: 0 out of 50000
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
  Number of DML statements: 0 out of 150
  Number of DML rows: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum CPU time: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
  Number of callouts: 0 out of 100
  Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
  Number of future calls: 0 out of 50
  Number of queueable jobs added to the queue: 0 out of 50
  Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10

07:44:47.59 (59073955)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE_END

07:44:47.0 (59117229)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|VF: /apex/Exception
07:44:47.0 (60290184)|EXECUTION_FINISHED
```

The other record (TSP_Reports) also doesn't indicate any error.

Comment: please refrain from asking for help in your posts. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do one thing here. When we create customer portal a exception page is created when you open this page you will found a line `apex:errormessage` change this into `apex:errordescription` and you will get the actual error message on screen.

You can use this to identify the issue.

Comment: Hi @Tushar, can you please be more specific about where do I execute this modification?

I don't see apex:errormessage on my VF page.

Comment: OK - I followed David Cheung's answer from this post 

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008rUKIAY

And I finally see the error! altough not on the debug logs but on the error page itself

Comment: @Dante yes for community we get most error is community exception page.